# Struct property not available

Tags: c#, winforms, struct, windows-forms-designer

I have a struct with five properties, which are set on button `_click` method (using Windows Forms Designer). After setting these, the bacground worker is run, using `.RunWorkerAsync`. The struct is then used inside the `_DoWork` method of the background worker.

However, when I call the struct inside the _`DoWork` method, the properties of the struct all has the value null. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am kind of new to C#.

**Defining the struct**

```
struct 
FtpSetting
{
  public String Server { get; set; }
  public String Username { get; set; }
  public String Password { get; set; }
  public String FileName { get; set; }
  public String FullName { get; set; }
}
FtpSetting _inputParameter;
```

**Button click function (only relevant code)**

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(ofd.FileName);
_inputParameter.Server = txtServer.Text;
_inputParameter.Username = txtServer.Text;
_inputParameter.Password = txtServer.Text;
_inputParameter.FileName = fi.Name;
_inputParameter.FullName = fi.FullName;
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

**DoWork function (only relevant code)**

```
string filename = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).FileName; // Code crashes here
string fullname = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).FullName; // ...But all the below values
string username = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Username; // ...Are null as well :-(
string password = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Password;
string server = ((FtpSetting)e.Argument).Server;
```

Comment: It's quite likely you need a class and not a struct which are only appropriate in very specific conditions (and which don't play well with mutability) (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `null` here are not the `struct`'s properties but the `Argument` all together.

You need to call the overload of [`RunWorkerAsync(object argument)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync) that takes the argument:

```
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(_inputParameter);
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the `public` part of the struct properties made it available inside `_DoWork`. It seems to be working now.